# AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'timeit' while doing timeit a python function

Tags: python, timeit

i want to timeit a python function or want to print best time it takes for executing my_function() for 12 iteration.
below is my code:

```
def my_function():
    print "hello"

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import timeit
    setup = "from __main__ import my_function"
    print timeit.timeit("my_function()", setup=setup,number=12)
```

but i am getting below errror

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "timeit.py", line 7, in <module>
    print timeit.timeit("my_function()", setup=setup,number=12)
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'timeit'
```

anybody please help..

Comment: `timeit.Timer.timeit` is what you want, I think.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You named your file `timeit.py`, which blocks the builtin module, so `import timeit` is importing your own file.  Name your file something else.

Comment: Hi BrenBarn, i have a question,i need to change setup variable, actually i am applying timeit on a function(lets say f1) from another function(lets say f2),so what should be my setup variable in this case. i am also sending argument x from f2 to f1. plese help